# Is there a specific name for objects that changes based on perspective?

Tags: modeling

[Example 1](https://twitter.com/i/status/1256496083175223297)

[Example 2](https://i.pinimg.com/564x/06/1a/50/061a508030f10e7e780443115a59fb9e.jpg)

I tried googling but can't find specific names.

Comment: I'd describe these as something like "perspective illusions", although I'm not aware of a specific name. Not everything has a name.

Comment: There is a name for one specific type of such an illusion - it's called a [Penrose Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penrose_triangle)

Comment: Err, every object except the sphere changes with perspective.

Comment: @joojaa, At first I thought that was a nerdy comment, but you are absolutely right. A more precise description would be "objects that change with perspective in an unexpected way".

Answer (score 5):

The term **ambiguous** is often used about optical illusions where an object can be perceived in more than one way.

Searching for **Ambiguous Illusion** and **Ambiguous Shape** on Google yields many interesting results. 
For example the [Ambiguous Cylinder Illusion](https://youtu.be/oWfFco7K9v8), the [Ambiguous Garage Roof](https://youtu.be/KtA6u1HIqbg) and the [Arrow always pointing to the right](https://youtu.be/UIR22SgrOz4).

The site of the [Best Illusion of The Year Contest](http://illusionoftheyear.com/) has many nice examples of similar illusions.

Wikipedia has a long and interesting [List of optical illusions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_optical_illusions) but none of them seems to be exactly what you are asking about here.

Answer (score 2):

Generally they seem to be called "Perspective Sculptures". But the term "[Anamorphism](https://www.newscientist.com/gallery/dn16197-anamorphic-art/)" might well apply.